# How to map/bind FParsec userstate?

Tags: f#, fparsec

I want to thread some state through a parser but I don't want to have a single type for state for all parts of the parser, because some types just don't make sense in some parts of the parser, but are needed in others. I could make a bigger more complicated state type with either optional values or a discriminated union, but I think that is ugly.

So I want to be able to map a function to the state of the parser.

Concretely, I want a function with the following signature

```
stateMap: (f:'a->'b) (p:Parser<'x,'a>) -> Parser<'x,'b>
```

Does such a function or operator exist in FParsec? If not, what is the idiomatic way to create it?

Comment: A lot of FParsec functionality is based on changed/unchanged userstate. I have no proof, but my sincere guess is that you may want to consider a complex userstate implemented as a Discriminated Union (or another combination) of both types, input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From checking the source code my impression is that there's no such method today and it's not that easy to implement. `Parser<_>` is defined liked [this](https://github.com/stephan-tolksdorf/fparsec/blob/master/FParsec/Primitives.fsi#L20):

```
type Parser<'Result, 'UserState> = CharStream<'UserState> -> Reply<'Result>
```

If there's a way to map `CharStream<'a>` to `CharStream<'b>` then we would reach the goal.

However investigating the [source](https://github.com/stephan-tolksdorf/fparsec/blob/master/FParsecCS/CharStream.cs) for `CharStream<_>` reveals some problems:

1. There's no `map` for `CharStream<_>`.
2. `CharStream<_>` is `IDisposable` which implies `FParsec` creates one instance of the `CharStream<_>` at the start of parsing and this is assumed to trace through the whole parsing process. Creating a new `CharStream<_>` based on an existing one and use that instead don't seem to match the design.
3. `CharStream<_>` inherits `CharStream` - So `CharStream` seems to do must heavy lifting when it comes to paging and `CharStream<_>` is just there to pair the stream with the user state. If `CharStream<_>` used a composition over inheritance we could create a new `CharStream<_>` that still used the already existing `CharStream` but with inheritance that's not possible. My guess is that inheritance is chosen here to avoid an extra deref and thus save a few clockcycles (performance is important for parsers).

So I think the idea of composite user states sounds interesting but from what I can tell this is not supported by FParsec right now.